# Amazon AWS Filezilla transfer permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, webserver

I have my instance of the Amazon AWS running, test page is up.

I am trying to SFTP the files to the server to display my website. I have Filezilla connected to the AWS server but when I try to move the files from my local machine to the /var/www/html directory, it says permission denied.

I just figured out I CAN move the files to the /home/ec2-user directory. So my files are on the server I guess. But when I try to move them from there to the /var/www/html directory, it still won't move them, permission denied.

I've been researching this for approximately 2 hours now but I haven't been able to locate the answer to this.

Any help is greatly appreciated, i'm so close! Haha

Thanks

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: For anyone that doesn't see comments below, you've got to use sudo chmod & sudo chown .

Answer (score 288, accepted):

To allow user `ec2-user` (Amazon AWS) write access to the public web directory (/var/www/html),
enter this command via Putty or Terminal, as the root user `sudo`:

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html
```

Make sure permissions on that entire folder were correct:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

**Doc's:**

[Setting up amazon ec2-instances](http://blog.matt.thomm.es/post/63427448565/setting-up-amazon-ec2-instances)

[Connect to Amazon EC2 file directory using Filezilla and SFTP (Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9BDvg42-JI)

[Understanding and Using File Permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

Comment: Still no luck...I cd to that directory and typed that and it still says permission denied. I even tried moving it on the command line this time instead of in Filezilla

Comment: I just updated my original post with the result of those. It makes no sense, I can't see a reason why I shouldn't be able to just move the files over there.

Comment: Shoot, my fault, I forgot 'sudo' That did the trick! Thank you so very much!

Comment: That's precisely what I needed, @aldanux. Thank you SO MUCH.

Comment: I have been struggling with this for a while! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! For those who did this using Bitnami (WordPress), just replace /var/www/html/ with your directory and put sudo at the beginning of each command and it should work fine!

Answer (score 89):

if you are using centOs then use

```
sudo chown -R centos:centos /var/www/html

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

For Ubuntu

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/html

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

For Amazon ami

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/html

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

Comment: This worked for me with AWS EC2 t2.micro 1+ for this. :-)

Comment: This is one of the best example and it works perfectly

Comment: works perfect. Before this command, files can be created via terminal with sudo. but mkdir failed. only after issuing this command, mkdir and transfer works

Answer (score 39):

In my case the /var/www/html in not a directory but a symbolic link to the /var/app/current, so you should change the real directoy ie /var/app/current:

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/app/current
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/app/current
```

I hope this save some of your times :)

Comment: This also applies for Elastic Beanstalk Apps

Comment: Thanks, you saved my ass after 3 days of cursing at my computer! :D

Answer (score 20):

If you're using Ubuntu then use the following:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu /var/www/html

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

Comment: The first one seemed to work. Do I have to execute both? I'm using WordPress and after executing the first command a few permission's errors have come up with some plugins.

Comment: @Coderhi, I'd recommend executing both since the accepted answer also follows the same pattern. Regarding your WordPress plugins. You can attempt reinstalling them afresh to the same EC2 instance.

Answer (score 4):

This work best everyone

`chmod ugo+rwx your-folder`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Answer (score 1):

To allow user ec2-user (Amazon AWS) write access to the public web directory (/var/app/current),
enter this command via Putty or Terminal, as the root user sudo:

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/app/current
```

Make sure permissions on that entire folder were correct:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/app/current
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after 30 minutes changing permissions, got into account that the XLSX file I was trying to transfer was still open in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

for me below worked:

```
chown -R ftpusername /var/app/current
```