# Warnings and errors appearing on site after changing ubuntu user permissions Amazon EC2 server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, opencart, filezilla

My site is running on a EC2 Amazon server under Ubuntu/Apache2.

My site was running fine until I changed the permissions for user 'ubuntu' by doing this command:

```
chown -R ubuntu /var/www/html
```

Now my site is spitting out warning messages and errors :(

www.kaysboutique.co.uk

I did this because I wanted to be able to write files via FileZilla after following this answer:

[Amazon AWS Filezilla transfer permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648712/amazon-aws-filezilla-transfer-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by running these:

sudo chown www-data -R /var/www/html

If not fixed, run sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html

Answer (score 0):

First to fix the pb try to restore the initial user and group for html directory by using this command :

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  /var/www/html
```

And if you need to add new user to www-data group use this command :

```
sudo useradd -g www-data [username]
sudo passwd [username]
```