# Can not copy file by Sftp to AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi folks I seem to have a problem of copying a file to my AWS instance by an Sftp with MobaXterm
I am receiving "permission denied" error. If I try to change ownership or permissions of my try/try2 folders, I receive "no such file or dirrectory" error.
I know, there is a similar question here, but it appears to have nothing new to what I have done ([Amazon AWS Filezilla transfer permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648712/amazon-aws-filezilla-transfer-permission-denied))
Here's what I have done (I am-root, of course):

```
[root@ec2-user]# ls
[root@ec2-user]# mkdir try
[root@ec2-user]# ls
try
[root@ec2-user]# chown -R ec2-user /try
chown: cannot access `/try': No such file or directory
[root@ec2-user]# chown -R ec2-user /try/
chown: cannot access `/try/': No such file or directory
[root@ec2-user]# ls
try
[root@ec2-user]# chown -R ec2-user/try
chown: missing operand after `ec2-user/try'
Try `chown --help' for more information.
[root@ec2-user]# cd try
[root@try]# mkdir try2
[root@try]# ls
try2
[root@try]# cd ..
[root@ec2-user]# chown -R ec2-user try/try2
chown: cannot access `try/try2': No such file or directory
[root@ec2-user]# chown -R ec2-user /try/try2
chown: cannot access `/try/try2': No such file or directory
[root@ec2-user]# cmod -R 755 /try/try2
-bash: cmod: command not found
[root@ec2-user]# chmod -R 755 /try/try2
chmod: cannot access `/try/try2': No such file or directory
[root@ec2-user]#
```

It seems like a low effort, but it's more, than it seems, I've been sitting on this for last hour and a half and I need a solution fast - have to upload a whole heap of things to future public dir.
Also tried using full path:

```
[root@ec2-user]# chown ec2-user /home/ec2-user/try/try2
[root@ec2-user]# chown  -R ec2-user /home/ec2-user/try/
[root@ec2-user]# cmod -R 755 ec2-user /home/ec2-user/try/
-bash: cmod: command not found
[root@ec2-user]# chmod -R 755 ec2-user /home/ec2-user/try/
chmod: cannot access `ec2-user': No such file or directory
[root@ec2-user]# ls
try
[root@ec2-user]# cd ..
[root@home]# ls
ec2-user
[root@home]# cd ec2-user/
[root@ec2-user]# ls
try
[root@ec2-user]# cd ..
[root@home]# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root     root     4096 Mar 20 04:18 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 26 root     root     4096 Mar 20 04:18 ..
drwx------.  4 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Mar 20 05:34 ec2-user
[root@home]# chown  -R root /home/ec2-user/try/
[root@home]# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root     root     4096 Mar 20 04:18 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 26 root     root     4096 Mar 20 04:18 ..
drwx------.  4 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Mar 20 05:34 ec2-user
[root@home]#
```

Where is my mistake? It's supposed to be a really simple thing

Comment: This isn't really on topic here - this is a question about some fairly basic linux usage, not about programming.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative place?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: helloV, at the end - I want to copy a .zip file from my local machine to my AWS machine, using MobaXTerm (simple drug-and-drop, using SFTP protocol). I received "permission denied error", so I presumed, it's due to ownership and permissions, so I tried to play with it - with no much luck

Answer (score 0):

I got it...It's all because of me connecting with RSA key. The AWS provides a key for login of specific user and to a specific folder, thus sftp protocol from 3'rd party software will apply only to that folder. Any subfolder will not be recognized for drug-and-drop software, such as Moba, Putty or similar, unless the connection method will not be altered. However, once inside the AWS machine, all the required actions can be easily performed without any problem (well, according to the permissions).
Moderators, please do not erase this topic - might be helpful to someone.

Comment: That's not the root of the problem. You were creating the `try` directory at `/home/ec2-user/try` but then doing (some) operations as if it was at `/try`.

Comment: I actually did try the entire path. It did change permissions/ownership, of course, but I was still unable to drag-and-drop files into the sub-directory. My main problem was inability to drag-and-drop